# Why does %autosetup perform patching BEFORE extracting sources?

Tags: linux, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a very straightforward arrangement -- one source tarball, one patch:

```rpm
Source: http://...../foo-%{version}.tar.gz
Patch: my-patch-for-foo.diff
...
%prep
%autosetup -v -n bar-%{version}
```

However, when I attempt to use the `%autosetup` in the `%prep` step, `rpmbuild` attempts to patch *first* -- before extracting:

```
/bin/cat ..../SOURCES/my-patch-for-foo.diff | 
/usr/bin/patch  
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8PV0PY
+ umask 022
+ cd /....
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /....
+ rm -rf bar-0.12.18
+ /bin/tar -xvvf -
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc ..../SOURCES/foo-0.12.18.tgz
```

For some reason, there is no error reported by `patch` -- but the extracted code ends up unpatched and my build fails later.

Using the ordinary `%setup` followed by `%patch0` works fine, but what's wrong with `%autosetup`?

I'm on CentOS-6.8, if it matters, where RPM is of version 4.8.0. Thank you!

Update, splitting the `%autosetup` into `%setup` and `%autopatch` does not work either -- `%autopatch` does not do anything useful. Because my patches are all in default format, I'm going to use my reimplementation of `%autopatch`:

```rpm
%prep
%setup -n bar-%{version}
%{lua:
    for i, p in ipairs(patches) do
        print("%patch"..i)
    end
}
```

Have I really found a bug, or am I doing something grotesquely wrong?

Comment: [This Fedora page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Autosetup_packaging_draft) says that it was added in 4.11 - I wonder if 4.8 has a buggy/preliminary version. I've never used it myself, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I observed the same issue on CentOS 6.7.

As mentioned above, RPM 4.8 supposedly doesn't support `%autosetup`; [autosetup documentation](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/autosetup.html) also confirms that it's supported starting from 4.11.

However, I found that `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` (installed from `rpm-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64`) does actually include a definition of the `%autosetup` macro, and `rpm -q --changelog rpm` shows that it was backported "recently":

```
* Mon Feb 08 2016 Lubos Kardos <lkardos@redhat.com> - 4.8.0-52
- Add %autosetup macros (#1265021)
```

Obviously that implementation seems to be broken, though.

[The EPEL packaging guidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL:Packaging#.25autosetup) says that "The %autosetup macro is available in all EPEL releases (**via epel-rpm-macros** for EPEL5 and EPEL6)" (emphasis mine), so I tried installing that package.  After installing `epel-rpm-macros-6-16.noarch` ([instructions for adding the EPEL YUM repository if you haven't already done this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)), `/etc/rpm/macros.zzz-epel-autosetup` contained a different definition of `%apply_patch` (which is used by `%autopatch`, which is used by `%autosetup`).  This fixed the issue - patches are now applied after the sources are extracted.

Comment: copying `/etc/rpm` from https://centos.pkgs.org/5/epel-x86_64/epel-rpm-macros-5-7.noarch.rpm.html also solved "`fg: no job control`" due to missing `%autosetup` in a legacy `rpm` distribution