# Why do I get an error when trying to build my own (simple) rpm package?

Tags: fedora, rpm, rpmbuild

I am practicing in rpmbuild and I run the example Hello RPM package the example run well, however, I build my own `gnuplot.spec` with this:

## Files:

```
SOURCES/
gnuplot-5.0.5.tar.gz

SPECS/
gnuplot.spec
```

## Spec file:

```
Name:           gnuplot
Version:        5.0.5
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        The gnuplot 

License:        GPLv3+
Source0:        gnuplot-5.0.5.tar.gz

BuildRequires: gettext
      
Requires(post): info
Requires(preun): info

%description 
gnuplot

%prep
%autosetup

%build
%configure
make 

%install
%make_install

%doc AUTHORS ChangeLog NEWS README THANKS TODO
%license COPYING

%changelog
* Tue Sep 06 2011 The Coon of Ty <Ty@coon.org> 2.8-1
- Initial version of the package
```

I run the next command:

```
rpmbuild -ba gnuplot.spec

Error:  /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.oAdSqX (%install)
```

Comment: That spec file looks very invalid.

Comment: This spec file (as edited) has a number of problems, but should not give that particular error. Is the above exactly what you have?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to indicate problems inside the install section, and the macro used there is `%make_install`. I would assume that this macro is not present on your system.

In my Fedora 32 machine, running

```
rpm -qa | grep ^rpm | sort | xargs rpm -ql | xargs grep -l make_install | sort -u
```

and looking into the files listed shows that it is defined in `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` and two of the other files gives hints like

```
if [[ $rpmver -ge 40800 ]] ; then # >= 4.8 (RHEL >= 6, Fedora >= 13)
```

and

```
- Use %make_install for rpm >= 4.8 in -newspec (#828455).
```

so that indicates that you need at least version 4.8 of rpm. However version is not necessarily everything, there are many macros that are defined in extra packages (like fedora-rpm-macros, cmake-rpm-macros, python-rpm-macros, etc).

The `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` file belongs to the `rpm` package though, although sometimes [it depends on other packages to work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42149368/23118).

So check if you are using rpm version 4.8 or above and verify that your `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` file contains a `make_install` macro.